# Node js http req and resp

Tags: node.js, http, response, req

Whenever I reload my page, the error message in the program is logged on the output terminal. I can't understand why.

```
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{

    if(req.url === '/'){
        res.end('Home Page')
        return;
    }
    else if(req.url === '/about'){
        res.end('About Page')
        return;
    }else{
        
        res.end('Error page')
        console.log('Error page encountered!');//?
        
    }
})

server.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log('Server listening to port 5000.......');
})
```

Comment: Perhaps log the URL and see what it is?

Comment: @Mureinik Thank You for the explanation, It helped me to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `console.log(req.url)` to the `else` branch would help diagnose the issue.

When you access a webpage via a browser, it attempts to look for a favicon at the `/favico.ico` path (i.e., in this case, `http://localhost:5000/favico.ico`), which will go to the `else` branch of your code and produce the error. If you use something like `curl` or `wget` to access `localhost:5000`, you'll get "Home Page" string without producing the error.